# SharePoint Timer service keeps failing

Tags: service

This is the error I keep getting:

*The Windows SharePoint Timer service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 7 time(s).*

The service then restarts and fails 5 minutes later and continues in this cycle.

Any ideas?

I am not getting a SQL error, just this..

Comment: Check event viewer? How's your disk space and RAM usage?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the Windows Event Logs or the ULS logs?

Answer (score 1):

Check the timer job history page in Central Admin (/_admin/TimerJobHistory.aspx) for any failed jobs. Use the view drop down to filter out successful jobs.